# How to estimate clustering (ARCH effects) in panel data

Tags: clustering, panel-data, arch

I have panel data of variable X consisting of 100-time points and 200 entities. I want to estimate clustering (ARCH effects) of X over time. Please suggest appropriate statistical method and implementation in R. Thanks

Comment: Conditional Heteroskedasticity models are much more common with high-frequency time series, i.e. many thousands of time points. Why don't you leave this effect out? You can use a "normal" VAR from the `vars` library in `R`

Comment: @Ferdi is it valid to use Arellano-Bond estimator with x as dependent and lags of x up to 5 as the independent variable.

Comment: Keep it simple. I have little information about your data, but until now there I see no reason why you CANNOT choose a simpler model like Fixed Effects, Random Effects or VAR.

Comment: @Ferdi thanks. I am interested in clustering of X over time. Please help.

Comment: Are you interested in the clustering of X itself or of model errors? Typically ARCH patterns are found in errors of some conditional mean model. I do not know anything about ARCH-type models for panel data, though.

Comment: @RichardHardy I am interested in clustering of X itself.

Comment: Just to note: ARCH is about **volatility** clustering, not any clustering.

Comment: @RichardHardy okay. Are there any other methods to measure clustering over time in general sense?

Comment: If you are interested in the unconditional distribution of your time series, then you may try any basic clustering technique. However, in time series we are typically interested in conditional distributions, and then the focus shifts to model residuals once the conditional mean effects have been accounted for.

Comment: @RichardHardy what about clustering in panel context?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have experience with clustering in panel data...

Comment: @RichardHardy okay. Any tip on general clustering techniques. Thanks

Comment: One of the best known techniques is [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).